# Can Rasa-X be installed on Rasa 2.0?

Tags: rasa, rasa-x

I am trying to install rasa-x on my office desktop in which rasa2.0 is installed. But it is not able to install Rasa-x as some certification issue. I have tried all trusted host commands can u please anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Just run the below command in the shell of your virtual environment.

```
pip install rasa==<version> rasa-x==<version> -i https://pypi.rasa.com/simple --default-timeout=10000 --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

Look [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/changelog/compatibility-matrix/) for dependency matrix for what versions of `rasa`, `rasa-sdk`, and `rasa-x` you are using.

This should resolve your issue.